# How can I correctly count rows in multirow form script?

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem with multirow form script modified by me. I added function who is filling ean, product_description and category_id inputs by values from ProductsData json array on the basis  of manufacturer_catalog_nr value.  Everything is OK when I'm adding rows singly and at once I fill manucaturer_catalog_nr. Script is filling rest of inputs. But when I add two or more rows script is filling only last ean, product_description and category_id inputs. The same problem is when remove row and add next one.

I know only that the problem is in counting but I don't have idea how can I fix this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  

 var count = 0;
 $('#add').click(function(){     
  count = document.getElementById("product_table_rows").rows.length;
  var html_code = '';
  var html_code = "<tr id='row"+(count+1)+"'>";
    html_code += '<td><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">P</div><input list="manufacturer_catalog_nr_list" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="manufacturer_catalog_nr_'+count+'" name="manufacturer_catalog_nr['+count+']" class="form-control catalog-filter" title="Numer katalogowy producenta. Jeśli go nie znasz, wpisz numer dystrybutora." required /></div><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">D</div><input type="text" id="supplier_catalog_nr_'+count+'" name="supplier_catalog_nr['+count+']" class="form-control catalog-filter" title="Numer katalogowy dystrybutora. Jeśli go nie znasz wpisz numer producenta." required /></div>';
    html_code += '<td><input type="text" id="ean_'+count+'" name="ean['+count+']" pattern="[0]|.{8,8}|.{13,13}" required title="Wpisz 8 lub 13 cyfr numeru EAN lub 0 jeżeli go nieznasz" class="form-control ean-filter" /></td>';
    html_code += '<td><input type="text" id="quantity_'+count+'" name="quantity['+count+']" class="form-control qty-filter" required/></td>';
    html_code += '<td><select id="unit_'+count+'" name="unit['+count+']" class="form-control"><option value="szt.">szt.</option><option value="m">m</option><option value="kg">kg</option><option value="kpl.">kpl.</option></select></td>';
    html_code += '<td><textarea rows="2" cols="50" style="width:100%; height:66px; resize: vertical; min-height:34px;" id="product_description_'+count+'" name="product_description['+count+']" class="form-control" /></textarea></td>';
    html_code += '<td><div class="input-group"><input type="text" id="price_'+count+'" name="price['+count+']" class="form-control price-filter"/><div class="input-group-addon">zł</div></div></td>';
    html_code += '<td><select id="category_id_'+count+'" name="category_id" class="form-control" required></select><select onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" id="" name="" value="" class="form-control green"><option class="form-control green" selected>Normalny</option><option class="form-control red">Wysoki</option></select></td></td>';
    html_code += '<td><textarea rows="1" cols="50" style="width:100%; height:66px; resize: vertical; min-height:34px;" id="assembly_'+count+'" name="assembly['+count+']" class="form-control" /></textarea></td>';
    html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+(count+1)+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button></td>";   
    html_code += "</tr>";   
    
    $.getJSON('../manage_categories.php', function(data) {  
    var html = "";
    html += '<option hidden selected disabled>Wybierz kategorię</option>';
    for(var option in data){
        html += `<optgroup label="`+ option  +`">`;
        data[option].forEach(function(item){
        html += `<option value="` + item["pc_option_value"] + `" >`+ item["pc_option_name"] +`</option>`
        });
        html += `</optgroup>`;
    }
    $('#category_id_'+count).append(html);
    });
    
    $('#product_table').append(html_code);
    
    $('#manufacturer_catalog_nr_'+count).change(function () {
        var input_catalog_nr = $(this).val();
        var check = false;
        for (var index = 0; index < ProductsData.length; ++index) {
             var product = ProductsData[index];

             if(product.manufacturer_catalog_nr == input_catalog_nr){
               check = true;
               break;
             }
            }
        if(check == true) {
        $('#ean_'+count).val(ProductsData[index].ean);
        $('#product_description_'+count).val(ProductsData[index].product_description);
        $('#category_id_'+count).val(ProductsData[index].category_id);
        }
    });
    
    $.getScript("js/input_filters.js",function(){
    Inputs_filters();
    });
    
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
    $('#' + delete_row).remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. Add an attribute `data-line='+count+'` in *manufacturer_catalog_nr* input,
2. Set var *"input_line"* with data-line value in input filling function,

```
var input_line = $(this).data("line");`
```

3. Add var *input_line* to input to be filled,

```
$('#ean_'+input_line).val(ProductsData[index].ean);
$('#product_description_'+input_line).val(ProductsData[index].product_description);
$('#category_id_'+input_line).val(ProductsData[index].category_id);
```

4. Enjoy.